# Row 2 of a row group established by a tbody element has no cells beginning on it

Tags: html, validation

hey guys i just finish make some code and when i validate those code i am keep get error like

**Row 2 of a row group established by a tbody element has no cells beginning on it**

And the code are below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>University of Hartford Asian Student Association</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<table>

<tr>

<td class="t1">
<img src= "logo.jpg" alt="">
</td>

<td class="WA">
<header><h1><i>Asian Student Association (ASA) </i></h1></header>
</td>

</tr>

</table>
<nav class="navbar">
<a href = "index.html">Home</a>
<a href = "event.html">Events list</a> 
<a href = "photos.html">Photos</a>
<a href = "contact.html">Contact us</a>
</nav>

<div class="Cdiv">
<header><strong>The list of different activities</strong></header>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Activities</th>
 <th>Time</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Cost</th>
<tr>

<tr>
<td>Bubble Tea event</td>
<td>Tuesday October 14th.</td>
<td>GSU Sofa Area</td>
<td>$5 for each, and we have different taste!</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Calligraphy Selling event</td>
<td>Tuesday October 7th.</td>
<td>GSU Sofa Area</td>
<td>$5 each name, written for people in asian calligraphy.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Chinese New Year Celebration event</td>
<td>Tuesday October 7th.</td>
<td>undecided</td>
<td>undecided.</td>
</tr>
</table>


 <table>
<caption>Drama Present</caption>
<tr><td>
<img src="oi2.jpg" width="400" height="250" alt="">
</td></tr>
</table>

<footer>
<p>
Designed by Han Yue &copy;2014<br>
If you have question, please email to <a href="mailto:yue@hartford.edu"         class="mail">yue@hartford.edu</a>
</p>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry about my code, i know is a little mess, but i really don't know how to fix this....someone please help

The error i get is :

" Line 43, Column 4: Row 2 of a row group established by a tbody element has no cells beginning on it.
"

PS: the line 43 is where the oi2 image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have missed a closing tag:

```
<tr>
    <th>Activities</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
</tr>
```