# HTML Validator table errors

Tags: html, validation, html-table

I got a problem with html validator it show me errors on "row x of a row group established by a tbody element has no cells beginning on it"
I'm beginner and I don't really understand why this isn't **correct** and **how** to fix it..

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_responsive.css">
    <link href="fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>La note enchantée</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <h1>ohmyfood</h1>
        </a>
    </header>
    <h2 id="note_title">La note enchantée</h2>
    <div id="note_corps">
        <p class="note_title_img"><img src="img/note.png" alt="note"></p>
        <p class="note_title">La note enchantée</p>
    <div id="note_font">
        <p class="sub_notemenu_title"><img src="img/note_bar.png" alt="notebar" class="note_bar1"><span class="underline_note_entree">Prélude</span><img src="img/note_bar.png" alt="notebarturn" class="note_bar_turn1"></p>

        

        <table>
            <tr><td>Ravioles de foie gras accompagnés de leur crème à la truffe</td> <td>98€</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Caviare osciètre sur blini à la farine de blé noir</td> <td>115€</td><tr>
            <tr><td>Homar et espuma de potiron mariné aux zests d'orange</td> <td>89€</td><tr>
            <tr><td>Foie gras de canard cuit entier, confiture de figue et pain toasté</td> <td>105€</td></tr>
        </table>
        <p class="sub_notemenu_title"><img src="img/note_bar.png" alt="notebar" class="note_bar2"><span class="underline_note_plat">Point d'orgue</span><img src="img/note_bar.png" alt="notebarturn" class="note_bar_turn2"></p>
            
        <table>
            <tr><td>Noix de coquilles Saint-Jacques sur lit de purée de céleri-rave</td> <td>102€</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Langoustine poêlée, purée de patate douce</td> <td>205€</td><tr>
            <tr><td>Mijoté de queue de boeuf et riz sauvage aux zests de citron</td> <td>169€</td><tr>
        </table>

        <p class="sub_notemenu_title"><img src="img/note_bar.png" alt="notebar" class="note_bar3"><span class="underline_note_dessert">Mouvement final</span><img src="img/note_bar.png" alt="notebarturn" class="note_bar_turn3"></p>
            
        <table>
            <tr><td>Macaron noisette et chocolat, glace au caramel brun et sel de Guérande</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Baba au rhum revisité avec son coulis de citron</td><tr>
            <tr><td>Tarte au citron meringuée destructurée</td><tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <p class="note_pied"><img src="img/note.png" alt="note">La note enchantée</p>   
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="infos">
            <a class="mentions_legales" href="mentions_legales.html">Mentions légales</a>
            <a class="contactez_nous" href="mailto:ohmyfood@gmail.com">Contactez-nous</a> 
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row 2 of a row group established by a tbody element has no cells beginning on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070095/row-2-of-a-row-group-established-by-a-tbody-element-has-no-cells-beginning-on-it)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I double checked it and saw nothing my bad